# Rename jquery.js to another name

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can we rename jquery.js to another name? Suppose I rename `jquery.js to jquery1.js` `then how can implement in ruby on rails`,

> **how application.js will come to know that it has to use "jquery1.js"??**

Comment: You seem to be talking about renaming the *file*. Is that really what you want to do? Or are you trying to rename the `jQuery` / `$` symbol?

Comment: you should rename rails1 too

Comment: No.. I want to rename the file. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is. The filename is irrelevant to the operation of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe im missing something, but jQuery is used on the pages generated by the server. These pages contain something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to change the code that is responsible for generating this line and if it's not generated you can change it in the header of your html document.

Chang it to whatever you renamed your jquery file in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.min.js"></script>
```